# Running a timeout on a specific request by decreasing a value every second

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to make a REST API using the Slim Framework. I need to provide an API, something like `abc.com/start?conn=10&request=10`

This will basically start a 'service' with Id 10 and for 10 seconds. I am using MySQL to store the values. I know that a Cron can run by the minute so how am I supposed to run a service for the specified amount of time and once that time is over, send a message to the user?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just pass the timeouts to your Slim request, it will abort for you when the timeout expires.

Comment: Kinda new to slim, how do i achieve that?

Comment: Oh wait .. I thought Slim was a wrapper for making requests. It's not. It's a router. How are you starting the 'service'?

Comment: run a cronjob command over the CLI with Php ?

Comment: cronjobs cant run per the second

Answer (score 0):

start the Service with exec and a cronjob to stop the Service on the desired time. You will find a lot of tutorials to write a cronejob from a CLI.

If you Need to do it in php you can manipulate the cron files ->
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2--net-19428

And there is this Manager for php. But never tested it.
https://github.com/MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager

Comment: cronjobs cant run per the second as far as i know, the lowest denomination is a minute. the timeout can be less than a minute.

Comment: what Service do you Need for less than a Minute ? ^^ 
No but honestly, you could implement a sleep and then stop the Service, but this will block a Task for every request. So i will think about your problem

Comment: It's more of a proof of concept kinda. It's obviously not a scalable product and isn;t public

Comment: then maybe you can do a list, with the conent (timestamp to run, Command to run) which you check in a Loop every second. but this also is a Performance leak like hell